# Choosing to not use delegates in a C# program

Tags: c#, linq, events, methods, delegates

I am trying to understand delegates in C#. I know they are a must in many scenarios like linq etc., but in simple console application, would my life be so miseable if i choose to not use it? I am not trying to escape it or anything. I just want to weigh the importance of using it over not using it. For example, I grabbed a c# console example from somewhere. How would I go about deconstructing this fine program that uses delegates into a supposedly unelegant version, that don't use one?

```
class Program
{
    // Define our delegate type: pointer to any method taking in string parameter and returning void
    public delegate void Write(string theText);

    // Method for output to screen
    public static void OutputToScreen(string theText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theText);
    }

    // Method to output to file
    public static void WriteToFile(string theText)
    {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("delegatedemo.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Assign a method to a delegate
        Write toFile = new Write(WriteToFile);
        Write toScreen = new Write(OutputToScreen);

        Display("This is a delegate demo", toFile);
        Display("This is a delegate demo", toScreen);
    }

    public static void Display(string theText, Write outputMethod)
    {
        outputMethod(theText);
    }
}
```

Comment: It takes time to understand delegates.  Back in the olden days, the Computer Science 101 class would lose half of the students when the subject came to pointers.  One extra level of indirection, it takes time to understand.  Delegates are not nearly as opaque as pointers so don't panic yet.  Keep trying to use them and you'll get the ahhhh! moment.  Nobody can really speed that up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the basics. Delegates are essentially *type-safe function pointers*. A variable of some delegate type is thus used to "point to" a method whose signature is compatible with that delegate type. Since function pointers don't do anything useful until said function is actually called, their appeal is allowing you to select the function to be called at runtime.

A simplistic version without delegates would involve getting rid of the variable part and just hardcode the function call. Of course the resulting program could not be functionally equivalent because it would lack the flexibility the delegates provide, but it could still produce any one specific result that the delegate-wielding version could:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Same runtime effect, but less flexibility: the effects are hardcoded
    WriteToFile("This is not a delegate demo");
    OutputToScreen("This is not a delegate demo");
}
```

A functionally equivalent version could be achieved by replacing a delegate with some scalar type and deferring the resolution of value to invoked method at a later time, using a `switch` statement or any other similar construct. However, this version would be more cumbersome to work with and open up the possibility of making a mistake that could only be detected at runtime.

```
public static void Main()
{
    DoSomethingWith("This is not a delegate demo", "display");
    DoSomethingWith("This is not a delegate demo", "write");
}

static void DoSomethingWith(string str, string what)
{
    // Same runtime effect and flexibility, but...
    switch (what) {
        case "display": 
            OutputToScreen(str); break;
        case "write:
            WriteToFile(str); break;
        // what happens if "what" is neither of the above?
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation in the first paragraph! Thank you so much for taking time to explain this concept to me!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. Just delete the delegate itself, delete the `Display` method, remove the `toFile` and `toScreen` variables from the `Main`, and replace `Display` calls in Main with calls to `WriteToFile` or `OutputToScreen`:

```
class Program
{
    // Method for output to screen
    public static void OutputToScreen(string theText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theText);
    }

    // Method to output to file
    public static void WriteToFile(string theText)
    {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("theFile.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteToFile("This is not a delegate demo");
        OutputToScreen("This is not a delegate demo");
    }
}
```

You can also get rid of the OutputToScreen method:

```
class Program
{
    // Method to output to file
    public static void WriteToFile(string theText)
    {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("theFile.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteToFile("This is not a delegate demo");
        Console.WriteLine("This is not a delegate demo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A delegate can be thought as an object that points to function(s).

If you don't want to use a delegate you could change the Display function to use an int parameter or enum and do an if statement to decide which function to call.

Sample with int:

```
class Program
{

    // Method for output to screen
    public static void OutputToScreen(string theText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theText);
    }

    // Method to output to file
    public static void WriteToFile(string theText)
    {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("delegatedemo.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Display("This is a delegate demo", 1);
        Display("This is a delegate demo", 2);
    }

    public static void Display(string theText, int type)
    {
        if( type == 1)
            WriteToFile(theText);
        else if( type == 1)
            OutputToScreen(theText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know *why* you want to remove the delegates.  Is the only reason because you aren't familiar with them?  Or are you trying to get a philosophical understanding of *when* and *where* they are useful?

Regardless, there are many ways to remove the delegates in this short program.  In this case, you would likely use a situation indicator (an enum or int) to switch between which functions you would like to call.  Here is one possibility with minor change from the original intent/structure:

```
class Program {
    enum WriteType { ToScreen, ToFile };

    // Method for output to screen
    public static void OutputToScreen(string theText) {
        Console.WriteLine(theText);
    }

    // Method to output to file
    public static void WriteToFile(string theText) {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("nondelegatedemo.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Display("This is a non-delegate demo", WriteType.ToFile);
        Display("This is a non-delegate demo", WriteType.ToScreen);
    }

    public static void Display(string theText, WriteType outputMethod) {
        switch (outputMethod) {
        case WriteType.ToFile: WriteToFile(theText); break;
        case WriteType.ToScreen: WriteToScreen(theText); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a lot of ways to do this without delegates, but I'm assuming you'd like to invoke any type of output in a similar way. I think an interface solves this just as well as delegates:

```
interface IWriter {
    public static void Write(string text);
}
class FileWriter : IWriter {
    public void Write(string text)
    {
        StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText("delegatedemo.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(theText);
        fileWriter.Flush();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }
}
class ConsoleWriter: IWriter {
    public void Write(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theText);
    }
}
public static void Main()
{
    new FileWriter.Write("This is a NOT delegate demo");
    new ConsoleWriter.Write("This is NOT a delegate demo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be made a bit shorter by using the preexisting [`Action<T>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and eliminating the `toFile` and `toScreen` variables (which you don't need):

```
public static void Display(string theText, Action<string> outputMethod)
{
    outputMethod(theText);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Display("Hello World", WriteToFile);
```

or

```
Display("Hello World", OutputToScreen);
```